# Touch event doesnt works in IOS7 Iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios7, mobile-browser

I am working for html5 games and everything was working well in chrome, firefox, safari, Ipad IO6, android, but it does not work well in IOS7 and Iphone4. The touch event does not work well. even the simply 'e.preventdefault' cant handle the double touch issue, its keeping zoom in and out. not like another device.
anyone had same issue ??

its part of my code.. sorry cant write too much.. I had some NDA

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var checks = Boolean(ua.match(/android/))||
             Boolean(ua.match(/ipod/))||
             Boolean(ua.match(/ipad/))||
             Boolean(ua.match(/tablet/))||
             Boolean(ua.match(/tablet pc/))

var touchable = checks && (typeof (document.ontouchstart) != 'undefined');
if(touchable){
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',mouseDown,false);  
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',mouseMove,false);   
    document.addEventListener('touchend',mouseUp,false);    
}else{
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',mouseDown,false);   
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',mouseMove,false);   
    document.addEventListener('mouseup',mouseUp,false); 
}

function getMousePos(evt)
{
    if(touchable && evt.touches.length>1)return;
    if(touchable)evt = evt.changedTouches[0];

    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) / game.scale.x,
        y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) / game.scale.y
    };
}

function mouseDown(e)
{
var mousePos = getMousePos(e);
alert(mousePos.x + "," + mousePos.y);
e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I definitely faced this issue while testing phonegap apps on an iPhone4 running iOS7. I removed the 300ms delay with fastclick.js, set all transitions to 0, removed the hover-delay, and there was still significant lag when scrolling. Unfortunately, the issue seems to be directly related to the iPhone4 hardware attempting to run iOS7. Technically while iOS7 is available on the iPhone4, iOS7 was not designed with the iPhone4 in mind.